# Foreign Key Constrait

Tags: mysql

Table A: Author Information

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    AuthorLastName VARCHAR(255),
    AuthorFirstName VARCHAR(255),
    BookTitle VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (AuthorLastName, AuthorFirstName, BookTitle)
);
```

Table B: Book Information

```
CREATE TABLE TableB (
    BookTitle VARCHAR(255),
    Subject VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (BookTitle, Subject),
    FOREIGN KEY (BookTitle) REFERENCES TableA(BookTitle)
);
```

Table C: Subject and Collection/Location

```
CREATE TABLE TableC (
    Subject VARCHAR(255),
    CollectionorLocation VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (Subject, CollectionorLocation),
    FOREIGN KEY (Subject) REFERENCES TableB(Subject)
);
```

Table D: Collection/Location and Building

```
CREATE TABLE TableD (
    CollectionorLocation VARCHAR(255),
    Building VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (CollectionorLocation, Building),
    FOREIGN KEY (CollectionorLocation) REFERENCES TableC(CollectionorLocation)
);
```

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `dbms_assignment`.`tableb` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
In TableB,TableC and TableD

Checking 3nf normalixation

Comment: It is a "Foreign KEY" - you need to reference a unique column or a unique set of columns. So - if TableA had two books with the same title (and there are lots of books with the same title but different authors) which book wouold the "Subject" in TableB be referencing? Also - name your tables better and try not to use mixed-case in SQL - it will only make your life more complicated.

Comment: i am trying to config this into 3NF (normalization from)

Comment: This isn't really the right place to go through talking design, but I think you have your relationships the wrong way around then. A specific building is in a single Collection/Location at a guess? I suppose a Collection/Location covers several subjects but it isn't clear whether a subject can be held in more than one Location. It also isn't clear whether a specific book (which is NOT uniquely identified by title - it just isn't) can be in some of those several Collection/Locations or is automatically in all of them. Get a fresh cup of tea/coffee and a pencil and paper and draw it all out.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, you only need to make an index for the referenced column in the parent table. The index can be a one-column index or a multi-column index as long as the referenced column is defined as the leftmost one in the sequence. The index doesn't have to be a unique one. Simply put, just create an index before creating tableB:

```
create index idx_booktitle on tableA(BookTitle);
```

Then you can create tableB without fail.

**HOWEVER**, has the issue really been remedied ? Maybe it's good in an error-free sense, but definitely not logically proven. As in reality, a book title can be so far as unique for a particular author, but never be true in a wider scope. Then, which type of index should we make for the book title? If it's non-unique, then the FK in tableB won't be albe to reference the intended one when multiple instances of the same value exist. On the other hand, if the book title index is declared unique, it will be impossible to add row for a book which has an existing title name but written by a different author.

To conclude, the book title is not a suitable column to be referenced. I would suggest using **ISBN**, as defined by professionals:
*The International Standard Book Number (ISBN) is a uniquely generated number assigned to a published book that acts as a unique identifying number for it.
The ISBN is often used by entities that manage, publish, and distribute books for listing and other logistical purposes. It enables booksellers, publishers, and even readers to find a book with ease.*